# Docker Container to run a period process which populates a database

Tags: docker, cron, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Using docker compose I have created a docker stack with a web front-end and a mongo database back-end. I need a process to run periodically, say once an hour, which populates my database by executing a `node.js` script. Ideally I would like something that will run as a docker container so I can simply define the node.js script and add the container to my docker-compose.yml file. I've read through some posts that use [cron](https://firefart.at/post/docker_and_cron_jobs/) to automate simple tasks. Would this approach be extendable to perform updates of my database too?

Comment: Why not just add the script to your containers crontab?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: @Nordle I've edited the text to be more specific.

Comment: @Shardj I haven't used cron before, can you recommend a docker image I can start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cron` can do the trick. Given that you're going to run a `Node.js` script, why don't you implement the scheduling in the script itself. Using `async` for example:

```
async function sleep(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, millis));
}

async function updatedb() {
    while(true)
        console.log("updating database");
        // ... update the database, await if necessary
        // then sleep one hour
        await sleep(60 * 60 * 1000);
    }
}

updatedb();
```

Set the script as the command to run (`CMD`) within the container

```
CMD ["nodejs", "/path/to/updatedb.js"]
```

This has the advantage of having everything in one place and avoids additional `crontab` configuration. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou! I like this solution. Would much rather keep everything in one place as you point out.

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped.